# No module named pandas_datareader - error

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I am trying to gain some more experience when it comes to Python with finance and I would like your help please.

I am currently going through a Youtube series, and in the first 2 minutes it says to download and install certain programs, one of these is pandas-datareader. The link for the video is below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BrpKpWwT2A&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcOdF96TBtRtuQksErCEBYZ

Currently I am stuck at 7:14

Every time I hit F5 to run the program, it gives me this message.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**pandas_datareader**'

Does anyone know how I can fix this error.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've installed pandas_datareader lib?

- Go to your terminal and type this :

`pip install pandas_datareader`

Comment: Hey, yes I installed pandas_datareader through pip. However it is not letting me use it :\

Comment: Are you using a virtual env to run python? If so then you need to install inside the venv. Check if you're using the right Python path as well.